# Dynamically change ag grid header name?

Tags: angular7

How to change the header of ag-grid dynamically using angular 7?

I have tried:

```
this.gridOptions.columnController.allDisplayedCenterVirtualColumns[1].colDef.headerName = "22";
```

but it works only in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Columns are updated with setColumnDefs()

[Refer this doc](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#columns)

```js
const col = document.getElementById('colSelect').value;
columnDefs[col].headerName = value;
gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs([]);
gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(columnDefs);
```

[Try this solution](https://jsbin.com/buditiz/edit?html,js,output)